# Rails Devise, using Onliner gem for list of online users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to use the onliner gem (https://github.com/kbokhonko/onliner) to display a list of currently online users. However, when I try to view the page that the list should be on I get "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass". Note that if I change "User.online" to "User.all" the error message goes away and I can view the page so it's not that my methods are in the wrong place or anything like that, I must just be doing something wrong in my implementation of the gem. If anyone familiar with this gem could explain what I'm doing wrong, that would be great! I'm sure that it's something to do with my def online method not being set up properly, but I'm not sure how else I would write it.

users_controller.rb:

```
def online
  @users = User.online
end
```

online.html.erb:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Users Online</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= user.user_type %></td>
        <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.user_type == 'admin' %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you wish to delete this user?' } %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

user.rb:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :onliner
```

application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter { |c| current_user.track unless current_user.nil?}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the gem, but seeing the code it seems you have correct configuration, so after all this did you restart the server? And if yes then are there any online users currently? May be if no user is online then it is returning `nil`. And if it is doing so then add a simple condition.

Comment: Yes, restarted it several times when I was trying to fiddle with it, doesn't change anything. It's not that no one is online because you have to be logged in to view the page. I think I'll just try to find another way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing everything correct, it looks like there is a error in the `onliner` gem. The `User.online` returns `nil` instead of an empty array in your case. I would suggest you to open an issue in the gem repo. or use some other gem.

Comment: Alright, I'll have to look for something else then. Ah well, at least I wasn't writing stupid code. Thanks anyway.